# Bitbucket Wiki TableOfContents

Tags: wiki, bitbucket, tableofcontents

I started with bitbucket and tried to use the wiki for my documentation.

Therefore, I created a folder "documentation" under the folder "wiki" (same level as home.wiki) and added some .wiki files.

Now I'm trying to display all these contents of Documentation/ as table of contents. Therefore, i added the line:

```
<<toc Documentation/ 2 >>
```

After commit and push my home.wiki page really shows a TOC, but it contains *only the first* file stored in the folder Documentation/. I want them all to be listed.

What is my mistake?

Best regards
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this failure had two reasons:

1. Through changes, multiple heads occured. ---> Merge them and commit&push the changes
2. The TOC-Makro does not update correct. Open the page containing the TOC in edit-mode via user-interface. Save it. Done. (refreshes the macro)

Answer (score 1):

One other reason a page might not appear in the table of contents is that the page will be missing a header. In my case, all pages with a header inside the content appear automatically

i.e.

```
= Heading =
```

inside the content (N/B: not title of page)